# Automating date picker using Selenium c#

Tags: selenium

I am learning Selenium and I want to practice how to automate flight search on a website , https://www.easemytrip.com/. Can I get some guidance about how to automate start journey date picker so that date is not hard coded into the test and I can run my test case with multiple dates I am using Selenium with c#

Currently the XPath for date element is like below //*[@id="15/04/2021"]

It contains exact hard coded date which I think may cause problem if I want to test for multiple dates

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We can find a next sibling element from the same parent in Selenium webdriver. This is achieved with the help of XPath locator. It is important to note that it is only possible to traverse from the current sibling to the next sibling with the help of XPath.

If you want to Select current date as start date,

**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class="active-date"]")).click();**

If you want to Select next date as start date,

**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class="active-date"]/following-sibling::li")).click();**

If you want to Select nth date as start date,

**driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class="active-date"]/following-sibling::li[2]")).click();**

Ref:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/find-next-sibling-element-in-selenium-python

Note: It does not work out of div class.[following-sibling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKsTo.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely try out your suggested solution.